# How can I get the text after the second bracket in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to get the value after the second bracket, I try to work with this one i created but it's not working properly and getting more complicated while I am having more brackets in each row.. Any idea. I uploaded couple images to understand the input and output.

```
Sub stringtest()

    Dim text As String, i As Long, firstbracket As Long, secondbracket As Long
    Dim extractTest As String, y As Long

    y = 1
    For i = 1 To 10

        text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        firstbracket = InStr(1, text, "[")
        secondbracket = InStr(firstbracket + 1, text, "]")
        extractTest = Mid(text, firstbracket + 1, secondbracket)

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 2).Value = extractTest
        y = y + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]   [image]

Comment: Meaning you are getting all values after `[?-???]` right?

Comment: Please post some sample data instead of snapshots.

Comment: Your example output does not seem to correspond to the code you've provided, so it's not clear to me exactly what you want. You could solve that by providing an example of the input and the output for a few specific cases. Also, if your data is delimited properly, you might be able to solve this without macros using data-->text to columns

Comment: @L42 yes I want to extract all the values after ['''']example['''''']....so extract example

Comment: @user3713336, did you try any of the answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try splitting by the second bracket, then using `Left()` to determine the length of the string

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetStringAfter2ndBracketInSequentialColumns()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, nextRow As Long, ub As Long, lr As Long
    Dim extract As Variant, found As Long, nextCol As Long

    With Sheet1
        lr = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        nextRow = 1
        nextCol = 2

        For i = 1 To lr
            extract = Split(.Cells(i, 1).Value2, "]")
            ub = UBound(extract)
            If ub > 0 Then

                For j = 0 To ub
                    If Len(extract(j)) > 0 Then
                      If Left(extract(j), 1) <> "[" Then

                        found = InStr(1, extract(j), "[")
                        If found = 0 Then found = Len(extract(j)) + 1
                        .Cells(nextRow, nextCol).Value2 = Left(extract(j), found - 1)
                        nextRow = nextRow + 1
                        If nextRow > lr Then
                            nextRow = 1
                            nextCol = nextCol + 1
                        End If
                      End If
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Test results:

[image: Results]

This is how one of the strings (cell A1) looks like after the split

[image: split]

---

**Edit**: measurements for all solutions provided so far:

```
Timers (with 100,000 rows)

0.824 secs - TextToColumns  (0.81054, 0.82812) - Output: same row split to many cols
1.679 secs - Split cells    (1.66796, 1.64453) - Output: sequentially by rows, then cols
3.757 secs - ArrayList      (3.69140, 3.78125) - Output: sequentially in one column
```

Comment: @user3713336: latest version outputs the results sequentially by rows, then by columns

Answer (score 3):

here's a short and quite fast approach

```
Sub main()
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Replace what:="[*]", replacement:="|", lookat:=xlPart
        .TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
        .Columns(1).Delete xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the fastest and simplest: +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's little different approach using `ArrayList`

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim arl As Object
Dim strVal
Dim i As Long
Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    strVal = Split(Replace(rng.Value, "[", "]"), "]")
    For i = 2 To UBound(strVal) Step 2
        arl.Add CStr(strVal(i))
    Next i
Next rng
For i = 0 To arl.Count - 1
    Range("B" & i + 1).Value = arl.Item(i)
Next i
Set arl = Nothing
```